# How to get the value of a dojo FilteringSelect?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using the dojo filteringSlect as followed:

```
new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
    name : "category",
    title : "Category:",
    placeHolder : "Select a category",
    store : new Memory({data : [],idProperty : "name"}),
    maxHeight : "250",
    intermediateChanges : true,
    searchAttr : "name",
    onChange : lang.hitch(this, this._submitCategory)
});
```

I'm creating the memory store adding the values with ID's such as 
`id=1`, `value=abc` and so on.

Assigning this memory store to store attribute of `filteringSelect`. I have added this widget to a form and calling `form.watch` to get the `OnChange` values.

```
this._formContentForASAP = new Form({
    id : 'asap24x',
    name : "ASAP 24x",
    style : "height:30px;width:250px;"
});
this._formContentForASAP.resize();
this._formContentForASAP.placeAt(this._asapcontentpane);
this._formContentForASAP.watch('value', lang.hitch(this, this._handleASAPFormChanges));
```

With this I'm able to get only the ID after `onChange`.

```
_handleASAPFormChanges : function(prop, oldval, newval) {
    // OnChange im able to get only the Id's
}
```

How do I get the values instead?

Comment: Can you not get the value by accessing the element from the store using the id that you are getting?

Comment: I can access it using the Id, but i wont be getting the edited values.
Like i changed the value in widget from EQPT to EQ, if accessed it using id ,i will get EQPT itself. Based on the value typed in filtering select i need to do validation and enable/disable submit button

Comment: If you need to get the value that has been edited (the value that is in the text box), then get the `displayedValue` attribute of the widget. It will return the value that is input by the user and not the id.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text inside the input field use this :-

```
    dijit.registry.byId(ElementID).textbox.value;
```

If you want the value corresponding to selected option use this :-

```
    dijit.registry.byId(ElementID).value;
```

where **ElementID** is the id provided to **FilteringSelect** element.

Comment: ```dijit.registry.byId(ElementID).get('displayedValue')``` seems nicer, no ?